# Bluetooth speaker pairs but won`t connect

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I am having issues trying to connect to a Bose bluetooth speaker.
It can be successfully paired but won`t connect.

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e036 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 174f:144d Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0eef:7902 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
02:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)
02:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd Device e232 (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Kernel version? Do other bluetooth devices work well?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - 64bits, kernel: 3.13.0-53-generic, I can transfer files from/to my phone. Suspect it is something to do with pulseaudio bluetooth-module

Comment: Your bluetooth adapter is supported with this kernel.  I will post a link with solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Bose Soundlink Mini Bluetooth Working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/453125/how-to-get-bose-soundlink-mini-bluetooth-working)

Comment: used to work fine (I know how to operate it), uninstalling blueman didn`t solve, every dependency installed

Comment: You can update kernel to the latest for 14.04. Maybe there is some regression. Run in terminal `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` and reboot after installation finishes.

Comment: any risks on doing this?

Comment: No risks at all. It is a standard supported kernel and you can always boot from the old one using grub menu. Nothing will be removed.

Comment: kernel: `3.19.0-18-generic`. No luck yet

Comment: No ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Then try deleting/removing the device from bluetooth devices and pair it again.

I tried this and it worked

Comment: to make it work had to do usermod -a -G bluetooth pulse

Comment: worked immediately! Thanks!

Comment: Mint 20 gives `Failure: Module initialization failed` from the second command. `sudo` does not help.

Comment: worked like charm. Thanks!!

Comment: This solution worked on Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: I am accepting this answer since so many people were helped by it ;)

Answer (score 3):

in my case this commands helped me

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start    
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Comment: On my machine it looked like pulseaudio did not start at all, even after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread in another forum that solved for me: [Bluetooth a2dp not working (connection logs incl)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218315)

Comment: I ended up making a clean install and the problem was solved. I am not able to test this solution anymore. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing a similar problem -

1. Bluetooth getting paired
2. Connecting to my Bluetooth speaker, not connecting to my Bluetooth headphone
3. in both cases the device was not listed under the sound output devices.

installing the `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` package and loading the Bluetooth module resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the 'magic trick' that I use to "fix bluetooth" when it's messed up in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

I keep this in a handy `~/bin/fix-bluetooth.sh` shell script.

Nothing else works, but this does every time, for me.