# Bluetooth not working on Asus SonicMaster laptop with RT-3290 Ralink driver running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, asus

I cannot seem to get the bluetooth hardware to work with Ubuntu. I can get a USB dongle working, but I'm sure the laptop has internal bluetooth hardware.

**Update:**

I have halfway succeeded in getting the bluetooth to work by doing **step 12** in the list directly below. I actually did this on Lubuntu 16.04, but will test it with Ubuntu 16.04 as well. I successully paired a bluetooth mouse, and am able to use it. However, it is laggy, but not to the point of being unusable. I am also able to send and receive files to my LG G4 via bluetooth. I am, however, not able to pair to bluetooth speakers. I tried pairing to two speakers of different brands, and it appears to connect briefly for a second and then disconnects.

**Update:**

I have also just gotten the bluetooth speakers to work on Lubuntu 16.04 by doing **step 13** directly below. I also was able to get it working on a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04. I posted the steps to do it as [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/877688/544803) below.

**What I have tried:**

1) Okay, so I have the Blueman Bluetooth Manager/BlueZ installed.

2) I know the bluetooth programs are functional because I can plug in a bluetooth usb dongle and eveything works how it should with the dongle. I am able to connect bluetooth devices with the dongle.

3) I also know that the laptop itself has bluetooth hardware apart from the dongle I plugged in, because I can unplug the dongle and boot into Windows 10, and bluetooth functions on the Windows 10 OS.

4) I left bluetooth enabled on Windows as well.

5) There are no hard buttons (that I can find) on my laptop to enable or disable bluetooth.

6) In UEFI, bluetooth is enabled.

7) In UEFI, Secure Boot is disabled.

8) I have tried`$ rfkill unblock bluetooth`from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/482651/544803) to no avail.

9) I have also tried `$ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` which sadly didn't work and gives the output
"Can't get device info: No such device"

10) I have also tried `$ sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd` and `sudo service bluetooth restart` from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/547208/544803).

11) I have tried reinstalling software as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/363509/544803):

```
$ sudo apt-get install bluetooth blueman bluez-hcidump bluewho python-bluez  bluez-tools
```

**12) I was able to get bluetooth partially working on Lubuntu 16.04 by following the steps from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/828925/544803) by [Klip](https://askubuntu.com/users/540797/klip). I had to modify the steps slightly to get it working though, so I will post my modified steps.**

1. `mkdir ~/tmp`
2. `cd ~/tmp`
3. `git clone https://github.com/alinefr/rtbth.git`
4. `cd rtbth`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install`
7. `sudo mkdir /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3`
8. `sudo cp -r ~/tmp/rtbth/* /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3`
9. `sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3`
10. `sudo nano /etc/modules`
11. Add `rtbth` to the end of the file, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> to save the file, and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.
12. Reboot

**13) I was able to successfully pair and output audio to my bluetooth speakers on Lubuntu 16.04 by following the steps from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/861247/544803) by [user631559](https://askubuntu.com/users/631559/user631559). Here they are below:**

1. `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
2. `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

**Other information:**

-When I open the default bluetooth GUI in *System Settings...* I am able to toggle the on/off switch.
-Whether the bluetooth is toggled on or off, underneath it, in the box that displays the devices you would be connected to, it says, "Bluetooth is disabled".
-When I try to run *Bluetooth Manager* it gives this error message:

```
Connection to BlueZ failed  
Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.
This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.
```

**Without USB Dongle**

[image: Bluetooth Disabled]

**With USB Dongle**

[image: Bluetooth Enabled]

**Without USB Dongle on Windows 10**

[image: Windows 10]

**Output:**

`$ rfkill list` gives the following output:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`$ dmesg | grep -i blue` gives the following output:

```
[ 1147.342967] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[ 1147.342987] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1147.342991] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1147.342993] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1147.342998] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

`$ lspci` gives the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

`$ lsusb` gives the following output:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4d15 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`$ lsmod | grep blue` gives the following output:

`bluetooth             520192  0`

`$ uname -a; dmesg | egrep 'blue|firm'` gives the following output:

```
Linux AsusUbuntu 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    2.141769] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[   28.577829] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   28.662579] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
```

Comment: Try to disable the Secure Boot from the BIOS setting of your laptop.  if it's enabled then any unsigned drivers can't be loaded.

Comment: Secure Boot was already disabled in UEFI. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bluetooth/+bug/1189721 .  One solution is in http://askubuntu.com/questions/453605/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04 ...but it involves editing source code and compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get bluetooth to work on Ubuntu 16.04 with a Ralink-3290 driver do the following.

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install git`
3. `sudo apt-get install dkms`
4. `mkdir ~/tmp`
5. `cd ~/tmp`
6. `git clone https://github.com/alinefr/rtbth.git`
7. `cd rtbth`
8. `make`
9. `sudo make install`
10. `sudo mkdir /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3`
11. `sudo cp -r ~/tmp/rtbth/* /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3`
12. `sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3`
13. `sudo nano /etc/modules`
14. Add `rtbth` to the end of the file, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> to save the file, and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit.
15. Reboot

It should be working now! If not try running `sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3` another time and rebooting again.

To get it working in Lubuntu 16.04 I had to install pavucontrol to get audio working at all, and then I had to install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth to get the bluetooth speakers working.

1. `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
2. `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`
3. `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`