# PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 15.10

I am having trouble connecting my Bluetooth speakers with a fresh 15.10 install (EDIT: applies to 16.04 as well). The speakers are connected however they are not listed as an available audio device.

I tried to load the Bluetooth module using:

```
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

The same speakers have worked perfectly on 14.04. Any ideas how I could properly load the module so I can use my speakers?

Comment: I’ve extracted the solution you posted as a [part of the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/689281/3) into a [separate answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121417/250300). Feel free to repost this answer using your account (to gain the respective reputation) or integrate it with your [current answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/689297/250300). Then please ping me, so I can remove my answer. See also [What do we do with this question that is really an answer?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17983/what-do-we-do-with-this-question-that-is-really-an-answer/)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Solved by using SimFox3 answer in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194006) thread.

> Bug and possible solution: actually I found a bug in that make the headset unusable, it seems that the pulse audio module: module-bluetooth-discover works only if started after the X11 session is up. So I have a workaround.
>
> Edit the file:
>
> ```
> /etc/pulse/default.pa
> ```
>
> and comment out (with an `#` at the beginning of the line) the following line:
>
> ```
> #load-module module-bluetooth-discover
> ```
>
> now edit the file:
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
> ```
>
> and after the lines:
>
> ```
>    if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
>         /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
>     fi
> ```
>
> add the following line:
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
> ```
>
> This way the Pulse audio’s Bluetooth modules will not be downloaded at boot time but after x11 is started.

Comment: You are my hero! Did you submit this as a bug report somewhere? This fixed it for me.

Comment: Worked for me too - this on the cheap & cheerful Lidl bluetooth SBL 4.1 which has previously failed to appear on googling it with Linux. Well done +1!

Comment: it works for 16.04 as well, believe or not this bug still exists and seems no one is going to fix this

Comment: I had the same problem on Debian Testing (stretch) and this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Great! The same problem in Debian 9 and the same solution...

Comment: Is there an upstream or distro bug report for this? I can't seem to find it neither in Ubuntu nor Debian nor upstream...

Comment: cool. works like a charm

Comment: It didn't work for me I am still getting error Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available

Comment: Tried so many things and that was the trick! Using Debian. How comes this is not solved on Debian and Ubuntu distros with everyone using bluetooth sound devices daily?!

Comment: Thank you man for real, i can confirm this worked on debian 9 stretch as well :)

Comment: umm.... what about people using wayland?

Answer (score 17):

The solution in 16.10 is:

```
$ sudo apt install bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

*This answer was originally posted as an [edit to the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/689281/3).*

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling was actually indeed needed.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes, it works after reboot, and such error appears later. In this case you can try the following, which works for me:

```
pactl unload-module  module-bluetooth-discover
pactl   load-module  module-bluetooth-discover
```

Comment: The unload seems to be the key here. Just loading (as suggested elsewhere) causes an error where it fails to load it. I couldn't get it to run with sudo though - but it worked fine without it

Comment: Had to do this in 19.10 also

Comment: This worked under 18.04 as well!

Comment: This totally fixed my problem. Linux Mint 18.3 (Sylvia). Half a connection to bluetooth.