# Bluetooth issues Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04

I upgraded from 15.xx to 16.04 and I have an issue with my bluetooth.

I can connect to the bluetooth device but I can't select it in the sound settings. I've searched the forums but I couldn't find an answer for my particular problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I Had exactly the same issue. Solved it with this thread:

[PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module 15.10/16.04/16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module-15-10-16-04)

After reboot reconnect your speaker and it would appear as a sound device.