# Bluetooth speaker pairs but sound doesn't work

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

My speaker pairs with Ubuntu 14.04, but sound doesn't work and there is a lock near the bluetooth indicator. I tried this solution without success:

[PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module-15-10-16-04)

Comment: The lock on the Bluetooth indicator means something is connected.

Comment: the speaker send a sound when does the pair with my pc, but it doesn't work

Comment: It's not automatic. After pairing you still need to explicitly select that audio output.

Comment: in the audio section i see the speaker but i can't select it

Comment: I solved in this way. I have installed pavucontrol. In terminal:
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
add this lines    [General] Disable=Socket
  Enable=Media,Source,Sink,Gateway
Save and exit from the editor
Then: sudo service bluetooth restart
cancel bluetooth speaker setup, and setup it again.

Answer (score 1):

[Copied from Question owner's comments from the question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829151/problem-with-my-bluetooth-speaker#comment1264691_829151)

> I solved in this way. I have installed pavucontrol. In terminal:
>
> ```
> sudoedit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
> ```
>
> Add these lines:
>
> ```
> [General] 
> Disable=Socket
> Enable=Media,Source,Sink,Gateway
> ```
>
> Save and exit from the editor
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> sudo service bluetooth restart
> ```
>
> Cancel bluetooth speaker setup and set it up again.