# Bluetooth speaker doesn't pair in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am running ubuntu 16.04 and a average ubuntu user and its my first post in askubuntu :)

I have Sony HT-CT80 bluetooth speaker and I am trying to connect it via bluetooth. It shows in bluetooth manager when I search for bluetooth devices but doesn't pair. I have no problem connecting other devices such as smart phones. 
I have followed some of the posts in Ask ubuntu tried installing pulseaudio by typing in the terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

but when I type

```
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

I get

```
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

I have followed the [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module-15-10-16-04-16-10/749415)

but the solution doesn't work for me and I get the same error

I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 4):

FInally, I manage to solve the bluetooth problem. I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS, thanks for many other users who have posted excellent solutions here and other linux forum. Here is my stepwise and collective effort for someone with the similar problem.

Open terminal (Alt+Ctrl+T) and type these commands and insert passwd whenever prompted

## updating system

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

## Install bluetooth manager

```
$ sudo apt-get install blueman
```

## Install pulseaudio

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
```

generally above commands install pulseaudio, you can check if you have pulseaudio now by typing

```
$ pulseaudio -version
```

If you still dont have it type

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio

$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

## editing default.pa file

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

comment out the following line by putting # infront i.e.

```
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

save and close the file

## editing  start-pulseaudio-x11 file

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
```

## find the following line

```
 if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null fi
```

## and add /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover just after it i.e.

```
if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null fi
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

save and close the file

Congratulations you are done with configuring ubuntu for bluetooth use ;)

## Open terminal and type

```
$ pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

you should get a numerical value in return, you need to type this command everytime you restart your computer which isn't practical so type in terminal

```
$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add above line at the end of the file and save and close it, it will save you from the trouble but remember to open terminal after restart

if you get error instead of numerical value type:

```
$ pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

and then retype the above command again, you should get a numerical value now

After that open blueman and try pairing the device and then select audiosink option (**If prompted for PIN type 0000**)
Open volume control and from top right corner and select the output audio to your bluetooth device and A2DP option. It should work then.

If it still doesn't work, try removing the device from blueman, restarting your bluetooth device and try again. Ubuntu needs patience sometimes :D

Comment: For ubuntu 18.04 only `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` was sufficient for me.

Comment: A small mark - after initialization you have to reboot your PC or will get an error by pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover